# How to copy a file from one folder to another using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

How can I copy a file from one folder to another using VBScript?

I had tried this below one from the information provide on the internet:

```
dim filesys

set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If filesys.FileExists("c:\sourcefolder\anyfile.txt") Then

filesys.CopyFile "c:\sourcefolder\anyfile.txt", "c:\destfolder\"
```

When I execute this, I get a 'permission denied' error.

Comment: Under what context are you running this script?

Comment: I get some output into one folder,i just need to copy that output from that folder to another folder where this output would begiven as input to another executable.

Comment: Are you running this as a .VBS script file, in IE, etc.? Can you do the same copy in a batch file run as the same user?

Comment: ok,i m srunning this one in an VBScript file.Let me just try that

Comment: I am trying to determine if the script has the right to write to c:\destfolder\.
Do you get the same error if you replace the last line with a shell call
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "copy c:\sourcefolder\anyfile.txt c:\destfolder\"?

Comment: Does the file already exist in the destination directory, and is the file read-only?

Comment: Glad I could help.  most times when an answer solves the problem it is marked as the accepted answer, by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 33):

Try this.  It will check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder, and if it does will check if the file is read-only.  If the file is read-only it will change it to read-write, replace the file, and make it read-only again.

```
Const DestinationFile = "c:\destfolder\anyfile.txt"
Const SourceFile = "c:\sourcefolder\anyfile.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
    If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
        'Check to see if the file is read-only
        If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then 
            'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\destfolder\", True
        Else 
            'The file exists and is read-only.
            'Remove the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
            'Replace the file
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\destfolder\", True
            'Reapply the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
        End If
    Else
        'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\destfolder\", True
    End If
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks tester,This solved my probs.Actually i had some probs with the path of the file name given-

Comment: Can we copy the files to Unix system with the above code? And if a username/password is required while copying, where should we pass that. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For copying the single file, here is the code:

```
Function CopyFiles(FiletoCopy,DestinationFolder)
   Dim fso
                Dim Filepath,WarFileLocation
                Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                If  Right(DestinationFolder,1) <>"\"Then
                    DestinationFolder=DestinationFolder&"\"
                End If
    fso.CopyFile FiletoCopy,DestinationFolder,True
                FiletoCopy = Split(FiletoCopy,"\")

End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer, based on (and I think an improvement on) Tester101's answer, expressed as a subroutine, with the CopyFile line once instead of three times, and prepared to handle changing the file name as the copy is made (no hard-coded destination directory). I also found I had to delete the target file before copying to get this to work, but that might be a Windows 7 thing. The WScript.Echo statements are because I didn't have a debugger and can of course be removed if desired.

```
Sub CopyFile(SourceFile, DestinationFile)

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
    Dim wasReadOnly
    wasReadOnly = False
    If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
        'Check to see if the file is read-only
        If fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then 
            'The file exists and is read-only.
            WScript.Echo "Removing the read-only attribute"
            'Remove the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
            wasReadOnly = True
        End If

        WScript.Echo "Deleting the file"
        fso.DeleteFile DestinationFile, True
    End If

    'Copy the file
    WScript.Echo "Copying " & SourceFile & " to " & DestinationFile
    fso.CopyFile SourceFile, DestinationFile, True

    If wasReadOnly Then
        'Reapply the read-only attribute
        fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
    End If

    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posted my finished code for a similar project.  It copies files of certain extensions in my code its pdf tif and tiff you can change them to whatever you want copied or delete the if statements if you only need 1 or 2 types. When a file is created or modified it gets the archive attribute this code also looks for that attribute and only copies it if it exists and then removes it after its copied so you dont copy unneeded files.  It also has a log setup in it so that you will see a log of what time and day evetrything was transfered from the last time you ran the script.  Hope it helps!
 the link is [Error: Object Required; 'objDIR' Code: 800A01A8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436431/error-object-required-objdir-code-800a01a8)

Answer (score 0):

Just set of vbs scripts to copy/move/delete a directory or a file:

Can convert long 260+ path into short DOS path to bypass the Windows limitation.

https://github.com/andry81/tacklelib/tree/HEAD/vbs/tacklelib/tools/shell

Answer (score -2):

Please find the below code:

```
If ComboBox21.Value = "Delimited file" Then
    'Const txtFldrPath As String = "C:\Users\513090.CTS\Desktop\MACRO"      'Change to folder path containing text files
    Dim myValue2 As String
    myValue2 = ComboBox22.Value
    Dim txtFldrPath As Variant
    txtFldrPath = InputBox("Give the file path")
    'Dim CurrentFile As String: CurrentFile = Dir(txtFldrPath & "\" & "LL.txt")
    Dim strLine() As String
    Dim LineIndex As Long
    Dim myValue As Variant
    On Error GoTo Errhandler
    myValue = InputBox("Give the DELIMITER")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    While txtFldrPath <> vbNullString
        LineIndex = 0
        Close #1
        'Open txtFldrPath & "\" & CurrentFile For Input As #1
        Open txtFldrPath For Input As #1
        While Not EOF(1)
            LineIndex = LineIndex + 1
            ReDim Preserve strLine(1 To LineIndex)
            Line Input #1, strLine(LineIndex)
        Wend
        Close #1

        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(myValue2).Range("A1").Resize(LineIndex, 1)
            .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strLine)
            .TextToColumns Other:=True, OtherChar:=myValue
        End With

        'ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        'ActiveSheet.Copy
        'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xlsFldrPath & "\" & Replace(CurrentFile, ".txt", ".xls"), xlNormal
        'ActiveWorkbook.Close False
       ' ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents

        CurrentFile = Dir
    Wend
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If
```