# Error: Object Required; 'objDIR' Code: 800A01A8

Tags: vbscript

Ok Issues I'm having before posting my code...  I'm getting this error

> Error: Object Required; 'objDIR' Code: 800A01A8 On line 19

When I skip over it using `On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo 0` I get `Error Object required: 'strFile' Line 22` When I skip over that It tells me that my last NEXT is not a collection...  Here's the thing the program worked beautifully Until I added in the steps for getting .tif and .tiff files.  Now even If I remove what I added it doesn't work...

The function of this program is to search a "source directory" for files that are archivable it then moves those files to "Destination Directory" and then checks them as unarchivable so that they aren't picked up a second time around.  It also make a log of what files were copied with date stamps etc.  Like I said it worked great but after tinkering for hours cant figure out what went wrong...

```
Option Explicit

Dim objLogFile, objFS, strFolder, strDestination, objFolder, eFolder, strFileName,  
strExtension, objDIR, strFile

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = "S:\Source"
strDestination = "Z:\Destination"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
Set objLogFile = objFS.OpenTextFile ("S:\Log.txt",2,true)

Go(objFolder)

Sub Go(objDIR)
    objLogFile.Writeline "Script started at " & Now
    If objDIR <> "\System Volume Information" Then
        For Each eFolder In objDIR.SubFolders       
            Go eFolder
        Next
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each strFile In objDIR.Files
            On Error GoTo 0
            strFileName = strFile.Name
            strExtension = objFS.GetExtensionName(strFile)
            If strExtension = "pdf" Then
                If objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes And 32 Then
                    objFS.CopyFile strFile , strDestination & strFileName, True
                    objLogFile.Writeline "Copied " & strFileName & Now
                Else
                    objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes =          objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes XOR 32
                End If
            End If              
            If strExtension = "tif" Then
                If objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes And 32 Then
                    objFS.CopyFile strFile , strDestination & strFileName, True
                    objLogFile.Writeline "Copied " & strFileName & Now
                Else
                    objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes = objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes XOR 32
                End If      
            End If
            If strExtension = "tiff" Then
                If objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes And 32 Then
                    objFS.CopyFile strFile , strDestination & strFileName, True
                    objLogFile.Writeline "Copied " & strFileName & Now
                Else
                    objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes = objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes XOR 32
                End If                  
            End If
        Next  
        objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes = objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes XOR 32
    End If
    objLogFile.Writeline "Script ended at " & Now
    objLogFile.close

    WScript.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: I should add this is my first VBS script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code... Not sure what exactly was wrong but I cleaned up the script and it works again.  Here is the code incase anyone else may need it.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = "S:\Source"
strDestination = "Z:\Destination\"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
Set objLogFile = objFS.OpenTextFile ("S:Logs.txt",2,true)

Go(objFolder)

Sub Go(objDIR)
    objLogFile.Writeline "Script started at " & Now
    If objDIR <> "\System Volume Information" Then
        For Each eFolder In objDIR.SubFolders       
        Go eFolder
    Next
    For Each strFile in objDIR.files
        strFileName = strFile.Name
        strExtension = objFS.GetExtensionName(strFile)
        If strExtension = "pdf" Then
            If objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes And 32 Then
                objFS.CopyFile strFile , strDestination & strFileName, True
                objLogFile.Writeline "Copied " & strFileName & Now
                objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes = objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes XOR 32
            End If
        End If              
        If strExtension = "tif" Then
            If objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes And 32 Then
                objFS.CopyFile strFile , strDestination &     strFileName, True
                objLogFile.Writeline "Copied " & strFileName & Now
                objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes =     objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes XOR 32
            End If      
        End If
        If strExtension = "tiff" Then
            If objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes And 32 Then
                objFS.CopyFile strFile , strDestination &     strFileName, True
                objLogFile.Writeline "Copied " & strFileName & Now
                objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes =     objFS.GetFile(strFile).Attributes XOR 32
            End If                  
        End If
    Next  
End If
objLogFile.Writeline "Script ended at " & Now
objLogFile.close

WScript.Quit()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your real world problem, you should consider:

1. using tools like xcopy or robycopy
2. avoiding traversal of (sub)folders that shouldn't contain user files; not scanning `c:\windows` or `C:\System Volume Information` would reduce risks and increase efficiency
3. a few `dir /s /b c:\can\di\date\*.tiff >> process-later.txt` could give a 'clean' list of files to process with your .vbs

There is one obvious error: You try to avoid `C:\System Volume Information`, but you compare `\System Volume Information` (no drive).

Not so obvious is: You can't use

```
On Error Resume Next
 For Each strFile In objDIR.Files
On Error GoTo 0
```

to 'skip the loop for nasty elements'. OERN just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Thanks I'll try playing with it more today.... I did try running xcopy however xcopy also transfered over the actual folders and subfolders when all I wanted was the files from withing every subfolder.  For the On Error resume Next only reason i actually used it was to skip the error and see the next forgot to edit it out of my code prior to texting.  I'll spend some time today working with your advice though and see what i come up with.  Thanks again!

Comment: dir /s /b c:\can\di\date\*.tiff >> process-later.txt  What does this actually do? Just need to know where and why I might impliment it in my code.  If you have a general statement of its application I can probably figure it out.  As for the error with the System Volume Information it still doesnt like my     For Each strFile In objDIR.Files line